# Reactivity within components in Vue Now UI Kit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently I'm just trying to change the colour of an icon withing a Vue Now UI Kit "tab" component using v-bind.  The code works as it should within the tab, but I cannot change the colour of the icon on the tab itself.

The second instance of v-bind in the code below, will change the colour of the icon within the tab on the button press.  The first instance does nothing: loanVerified variable is updated but the new color is not rendered to the tab.  Changing the initial value of loanVerified and reloading the page will change the colour upon refresh.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```js
<template>
  <div class="starter-page">
    <div class="section text-center">
      <h3>Enter details here</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <tabs type="primary">
        <tab-pane>
          <span slot="label">
            <span class="now-ui-icons objects_umbrella-13" v-bind:class="{ verified: loanVerified }">   </span>
            Loan Details
          </span>
          <span v-bind:class="{verified: loanVerified }">
            {{loanVerified}}
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="now-ui-icons objects_umbrella-13" v-bind:class="{ verified: loanVerified }"></i>
            Loan Details
          </span>
          <loan-details v-on:childToParent="changeLoanVerified"></loan-details>
        </tab-pane>
        <tab-pane label="Basic Details">
          <basic-details></basic-details>
        </tab-pane>
        <tab-pane label="Employment">
          <employment-details></employment-details>
        </tab-pane>
        <tab-pane label="Assets & Liabilities">
          <assets-liabilities></assets-liabilities>
        </tab-pane>
        <tab-pane label="Documents">
          <supporting-docs></supporting-docs>
        </tab-pane>
      </tabs>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Tabs, TabPane, BasicDetails, EmploymentDetails, AssetsLiabilities, SupportingDocs, LoanDetails } from '@/components';

  export default {
  components: {
    Tabs,
    TabPane,
    BasicDetails,
    EmploymentDetails,
    AssetsLiabilities,
    SupportingDocs,
    LoanDetails
  },
  data() {
    return {
        loanVerified: true
      };
  },
  methods: {
    changeLoanVerified (value) {
      this.loanVerified = value;    
      }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
.starter-page {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 95px);
}
.verified {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
<span slot="label">
   <span class="now-ui-icons objects_umbrella-13" v-bind:class="{ verified: loanVerified }">   </span>
   Loan Details
</span>
```

changed

```
<template v-slot:label>
  <span class="now-ui-icons objects_umbrella-13" :class="{ verified: loanVerified }">   </span>
  {{loanVerified}} Loan Details
</template>
```

[image]

[Vue 2.6 after the use of slots changed, click to view the document, can not see please search after vue2.6 version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Comment: Thanks - that works.  Do you mind explaining why that works and the initial example does not?

Comment: @ZakAvery I don't know what vue source changed after 2.6.0, But the official document says so，In 2.6.0, we introduced a new unified syntax (the v-slot directive) for named and scoped slots. It replaces the slot and slot-scope attributes, which are now deprecated, but have not been removed and are still documented here. The rationale for introducing the new syntax is described in this RFC.
I also gave the link above, you can go in to have a look.